# get all active categories and subcategories in product listing page [Magento]

Tags: magento

My categories and subcategories hierarchy to a product listing page :

- Products

  - Refrigerator

    - back-bar fridges

      - Product listing(here)

Now, what i'm trying to get is while i'm in product listing page i want to get all the parent categories and subcategories with respective links.

What i tried is :

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

But this doesn't render in product listing page. So how can i get all the active categories and subcategories in product listing page their links that will take me to the respective category/subcategory page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $currentCategoryId = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
        $curentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategoryId);
        $path = $curentCategory->getPath();
        // $path will return category IDs like "1/5/16/30/45" : Here, 1 is the main root category & 2 is the Default magento root category. After these, you will get the category Ids by hierarchy . 

        /*
        * Output "1/5/16/30/45" will have following hierarchy 
        *1-
        *  2-
        *    16-
        *      30-
        *        45
        */
        // later you can explode by slash(/) and go ahead with your further display logics
?>
```

Comment: then, how to get category name with category id ?

Comment: Once you explode it into array of category ids, load the category and get name using following in foreach : $name = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(id)->getName();

Comment: Ok, but its escaping the middle subcategories. :( It gave me 1/3/444 (blank/root catalog/products) It escaped all the subcategory in the hierarchy. In My case it escaped `regrigerator/back-bar fridges`

Comment: Please check the category hierarchy in backend. If still issue persists, check out another method "->getParentCategories()" on your loaded current category object.

Comment: `$path = $curentCategory->getParentCategories()->getPath();` **Fatal error : call to a member function getPath()**

Comment: You will get the info in getParentCategories() only. Checkout this link, it will help you : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4606/how-to-get-top-parent-category-from-current-category-object